# Can we pass a input hidden variable to a new page on user click event.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hidden-field

Have a click event, which will take to a new page.

```
    $(".class").click(function()
            {
                location.href = "xxx.html";
}

<input type="hidden" value="hidden" id="someid" name="somename"/>
```

Now, can i get this "somename" hidden variable in xxx.html

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No you can not get hidden variable of one html page at any other page. Instead you should pass value of this hidden variable as query string.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to pass the hidden variable, you can pass as a GET variable.

```
$(".class").click(function()
{
    location.href = "xxx.html?somename="+$('#someid').val();
}

<input type="hidden" value="hidden" id="someid" name="somename"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to get the value of hidden field, you can use val() to get it. You can use id selector.

```
$(".class").click(function() {
    location.href = $('#someid').val();
    //OR
    location.href = document.getElementById('someid').value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the given solutions, you could also set a cookie, store the value in the cookie before refering to the next site and then read the cookie out on the target page.